# Visual studio generated test XML and XSLT schema mapping throws an error : XML document must contain a root level element

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, xsd, biztalk

maybe someone has an answer or idea. Thank you.

This is to debug a custom XSLT mapping in a deployed Biztalk Server app. I get errors with it and it's not easy to track what is going wrong. BTW, maybe it's not necessary to fully understand Biztalk at all here, because it's mostly an XML, XSLT related issue, I guess.

So, I went back to the basics and I generated a very simple XSLT from a map that works in the deployed app and I wanted to visually see the result in an XML output directly in Visual Studio. From there I thought I could experiment with my custom XSLT and determine and fix the errors more easily than in the deployed Biztalk app (log is not totally helpful).

So here what I have done, if it makes sense : (see code below as required - sorry I had to trim the code a bit to fit in the post)

In Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate,

1. I have this XSLT that I generated from a functional Biztalk Server map (validate map command). The map has a Biztalk HL7 accelerator ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF xsd schema on the left (input), and our custom output schema on the right; This is for and incoming message.
2. I generated a test file (generate instance command) from the ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF xsd schema as a source XML file to test the XSLT;
3. I selected that XML file as the input for the XSLT to process in VS;
4. I process that file with the command in menu XML / Start XSLT without debugging, and Visual studio gives me just one error :

XML document must contain a root level element.

(The output file is actually empty)

Any idea on what I'm missing please?

Thanks

Claude

**Biztalk accelarator Hl7 ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF xsd schema on the left :**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
    - <xs:schema xmlns="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Segments" targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:import schemaLocation="BTAHL7Schemas.segments_25" namespace="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Segments" /> 
    - <xs:annotation>
    - <xs:appinfo>
      <b:schemaInfo standards_version="HL7.DBVersion.1_5" document_type="HL7 2X Schema" version="2.0.0104.0.2.0" root_reference="ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF" /> 
    - <b:references>
      <b:reference targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/DataTypes" /> 
      <b:reference targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Segments" /> 
      <b:reference targetNamespace="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Tables" /> 
      </b:references>
      </xs:appinfo>
      </xs:annotation>
    - <xs:element name="ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF">
    - <xs:complexType>
    - <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="SFT_SoftwareSegment" type="ns0:SFT" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="EVN_EventType" type="ns0:EVN" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PID_PatientIdentification" type="ns0:PID" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PD1_PatientAdditionalDemographic" type="ns0:PD1" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ROL_Role" type="ns0:ROL" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="NK1_NextOfKinAssociatedParties" type="ns0:NK1" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="PV1_PatientVisit" type="ns0:PV1" /> 
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PV2_PatientVisitAdditionalInformation" type="ns0:PV2" /> 
 ....snip....


  <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PDA_PatientDeathAndAutopsy" type="ns0:PDA" /> 


 </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

---

XML instance generated in Visusal studio from schema, trimmed, with some data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<root>
  <PID_PatientIdentification>
    <PID_1_SetIdPid>PID_1_SetIdPid_0</PID_1_SetIdPid>

 ....snip....

<PID_3_PatientIdentifierList>
  <CX_0_IdNumber>1</CX_0_IdNumber>
  <CX_1_CheckDigit>CX_1_CheckDigit_0</CX_1_CheckDigit>
  <CX_2_CheckDigitScheme>CX_2_CheckDigitScheme_0</CX_2_CheckDigitScheme>
  <CX_3_AssigningAuthority>
    <CX_3_0_NamespaceId>CX_3_0_NamespaceId_0</CX_3_0_NamespaceId>
    <CX_3_1_UniversalId>CX_3_1_UniversalId_0</CX_3_1_UniversalId>
    <CX_3_2_UniversalIdType>CX_3_2_UniversalIdType_0</CX_3_2_UniversalIdType>
  </CX_3_AssigningAuthority>
  <CX_4_IdentifierTypeCode>SSN</CX_4_IdentifierTypeCode>
  <CX_5_AssigningFacility>
    <CX_5_0_NamespaceId>CX_5_0_NamespaceId_0</CX_5_0_NamespaceId>
    <CX_5_1_UniversalId>CX_5_1_UniversalId_0</CX_5_1_UniversalId>
    <CX_5_2_UniversalIdType>CX_5_2_UniversalIdType_0</CX_5_2_UniversalIdType>
  </CX_5_AssigningFacility>
  <CX_6_EffectiveDate>CX_6_EffectiveDate_0</CX_6_EffectiveDate>
  <CX_7_ExpirationDate>CX_7_ExpirationDate_0</CX_7_ExpirationDate>
  <CX_8_AssigningJurisdiction>
    <CX_8_0_Identifier>CX_8_0_Identifier_0</CX_8_0_Identifier>
    <CX_8_1_Text>CX_8_1_Text_0</CX_8_1_Text>
    <CX_8_2_NameOfCodingSystem>CX_8_2_NameOfCodingSystem_0</CX_8_2_NameOfCodingSystem>
    <CX_8_3_AlternateIdentifier>CX_8_3_AlternateIdentifier_0</CX_8_3_AlternateIdentifier>
    <CX_8_4_AlternateText>CX_8_4_AlternateText_0</CX_8_4_AlternateText>

 ....snip....

  </PID_PatientIdentification>


 ....snip....

</root>
```

---

**XSLT generated from working Biztalk map :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 userCSharp" 
                version="1.0" 
                xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema" 
                xmlns:s1="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Tables" 
                xmlns:s2="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X" 
                xmlns:s3="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/Segments" 
                xmlns:s4="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X/2.5/DataTypes" 
                xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
    <form1>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.3_SendingApplication/HD.0_NamespaceId">
        <MSH_3-SendingApplication>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.3_SendingApplication/HD.0_NamespaceId/text()" />
        </MSH_3-SendingApplication>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.4_SendingFacility/HD.0_NamespaceId">
        <MSH_4-SendingFacility>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.4_SendingFacility/HD.0_NamespaceId/text()" />
        </MSH_4-SendingFacility>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.5_ReceivingApplication/HD.0_NamespaceId">
        <MSH_5-ReceiveApplication>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.5_ReceivingApplication/HD.0_NamespaceId/text()" />
        </MSH_5-ReceiveApplication>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.6_ReceivingFacility/HD.0_NamespaceId">
        <MSH_6-ReceiveFacility>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.6_ReceivingFacility/HD.0_NamespaceId/text()" />
        </MSH_6-ReceiveFacility>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.0_MessageType">
        <MSH_9-MessageType>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.0_MessageType/text()" />
        </MSH_9-MessageType>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.1_TriggerEvent">
        <MSH_9-EventTrigger>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.9_MessageType/CM_MSG.1_TriggerEvent/text()" />
        </MSH_9-EventTrigger>
      </xsl:if>
      <MSH_10-MessageControlID>
        <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s2:MSH_25_GLO_DEF/MSH/MSH.10_MessageControlId/text()" />
      </MSH_10-MessageControlID>
      <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:MyConcat()" />
      <EventTimeStamp>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var:v1" />
      </EventTimeStamp>
      <xsl:variable name="var:v2" select="userCSharp:TSTime()" />
      <PID_33-ApplicationDate>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var:v2" />
      </PID_33-ApplicationDate>
      <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_3_PatientIdentifierList">
        <PID_3_PatientIdentifierList>
          <xsl:if test="CX_0_IdNumber">
            <IdNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="CX_0_IdNumber/text()" />
            </IdNumber>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="CX_4_IdentifierTypeCode">
            <IdentifierTypeCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="CX_4_IdentifierTypeCode/text()" />
            </IdentifierTypeCode>
          </xsl:if>
        </PID_3_PatientIdentifierList>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_5_PatientName/XPN_0_FamilyName/XPN_0_0_Surname">
        <PID_5-LastName>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_5_PatientName/XPN_0_FamilyName/XPN_0_0_Surname/text()" />
        </PID_5-LastName>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_5_PatientName/XPN_1_GivenName">
        <PID_5-FirstName>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_5_PatientName/XPN_1_GivenName/text()" />
        </PID_5-FirstName>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_7_DateTimeOfBirth/TS_0_Time">
        <PID_7-BirthDate>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_7_DateTimeOfBirth/TS_0_Time/text()" />
        </PID_7-BirthDate>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_15_PrimaryLanguage/CE_0_Identifier">
        <PID_15-PreferredLanguage>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_15_PrimaryLanguage/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
        </PID_15-PreferredLanguage>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:variable name="var:v3" select="userCSharp:ConvertSex(string(InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_8_AdministrativeSex/text()))" />
      <PID_8-Sex>
        <xsl:value-of select="$var:v3" />
      </PID_8-Sex>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_13_PhoneNumberHome/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber">
        <PID_13-HomePhone>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_13_PhoneNumberHome/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber/text()" />
        </PID_13-HomePhone>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_14_PhoneNumberBusiness/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber">
        <PID_14-WorkPhone>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_14_PhoneNumberBusiness/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber/text()" />
        </PID_14-WorkPhone>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_0_StreetAddress/XAD_0_0_StreetOrMailingAddress">
        <PID_11-Address>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_0_StreetAddress/XAD_0_0_StreetOrMailingAddress/text()" />
        </PID_11-Address>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_2_City">
        <PID_11-City>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_2_City/text()" />
        </PID_11-City>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_3_StateOrProvince">
        <PID_11-IDState>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_3_StateOrProvince/text()" />
        </PID_11-IDState>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_4_ZipOrPostalCode">
        <PID_11-ZIPCode>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_11_PatientAddress/XAD_4_ZipOrPostalCode/text()" />
        </PID_11-ZIPCode>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_13_PhoneNumberHome/XTN_3_EmailAddress">
        <Email>
          <xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/PID_PatientIdentification/PID_13_PhoneNumberHome/XTN_3_EmailAddress/text()" />
        </Email>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/NK1_NextOfKinAssociatedParties">
        <xsl:for-each select="NK1_2_Name">
          <xsl:for-each select="XPN_0_FamilyName">
            <Nk1>
              <NK1_1-SetID>
                <xsl:value-of select="../../NK1_1_SetIdNk1/text()" />
              </NK1_1-SetID>
              <NK1_2-DelegateLastName>
                <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
              </NK1_2-DelegateLastName>
              <xsl:if test="../XPN_1_GivenName">
                <NK1_2-DelegateFirstName>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../XPN_1_GivenName/text()" />
                </NK1_2-DelegateFirstName>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="../../NK1_3_Relationship/CE_0_Identifier">
                <NK1_3-IDDelegateRelationship>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../../NK1_3_Relationship/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
                </NK1_3-IDDelegateRelationship>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="../../NK1_5_PhoneNumber/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber">
                <NK1_5-DelegateHomePhone>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../../NK1_5_PhoneNumber/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber/text()" />
                </NK1_5-DelegateHomePhone>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="../../NK1_5_PhoneNumber/XTN_3_EmailAddress">
                <NK1_5-DelegateEmail>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../../NK1_5_PhoneNumber/XTN_3_EmailAddress/text()" />
                </NK1_5-DelegateEmail>
              </xsl:if>
              <xsl:if test="../../NK1_6_BusinessPhoneNumber/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber">
                <NK1_6-DelegateWorkPhone>
                  <xsl:value-of select="../../NK1_6_BusinessPhoneNumber/XTN_0_TelephoneNumber/text()" />
                </NK1_6-DelegateWorkPhone>
              </xsl:if>
            </Nk1>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/AL1_PatientAllergyInformation">
        <AL1_PatientAllergy>
          <AL1_1-SetID>
            <xsl:value-of select="AL1_1_SetIdAl1/text()" />
          </AL1_1-SetID>
          <xsl:if test="AL1_2_AllergenTypeCode/CE_0_Identifier">
            <AL1_2-AllergenTypeCode>
              <xsl:value-of select="AL1_2_AllergenTypeCode/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
            </AL1_2-AllergenTypeCode>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="AL1_3_AllergenCodeMnemonicDescription/CE_0_Identifier">
            <AL1_3-AllergyDescription>
              <xsl:value-of select="AL1_3_AllergenCodeMnemonicDescription/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
            </AL1_3-AllergyDescription>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="AL1_4_AllergySeverityCode/CE_0_Identifier">
            <AL1_4-Severity>
              <xsl:value-of select="AL1_4_AllergySeverityCode/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
            </AL1_4-Severity>
          </xsl:if>
        </AL1_PatientAllergy>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/OBX_ObservationResult">
        <xsl:for-each select="OBX_5_ObservationValue">
          <OBX_ObservationResult>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_1_SetIdObx">
              <OBX_1_SetIDObx>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_1_SetIdObx/text()" />
              </OBX_1_SetIDObx>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_2_ValueType">
              <OBX_2_ValueType>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_2_ValueType/text()" />
              </OBX_2_ValueType>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier/CE_0_Identifier">
              <OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier/CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
              </OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier/CE_1_Text">
              <OBX_3_Text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_3_ObservationIdentifier/CE_1_Text/text()" />
              </OBX_3_Text>
            </xsl:if>
            <OBX_5_ObservationValue>
              <xsl:value-of select="./text()" />
            </OBX_5_ObservationValue>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_6_Units/CE_1_Text">
              <OBX_6_Units>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_6_Units/CE_1_Text/text()" />
              </OBX_6_Units>
            </xsl:if>
            <OBX_11_ObservationResultStatus>
              <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_11_ObservationResultStatus/text()" />
            </OBX_11_ObservationResultStatus>
            <xsl:if test="../OBX_14_DateTimeOfTheObservation">
              <OBX_14_DataTimeOfTheObservation>
                <xsl:value-of select="../OBX_14_DateTimeOfTheObservation/text()" />
              </OBX_14_DataTimeOfTheObservation>
            </xsl:if>
          </OBX_ObservationResult>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="InputMessagePart_1/s2:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF/DG1_Diagnosis">
        <xsl:for-each select="DG1_3_DiagnosisCodeDg1">
          <DG1_Diagnosis>
            <xsl:if test="CE_0_Identifier">
              <DG1_3_DiagnosisCodeDG1>
                <xsl:value-of select="CE_0_Identifier/text()" />
              </DG1_3_DiagnosisCodeDG1>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../DG1_4_DiagnosisDescription">
              <DG1_4_DiagnosisDescription>
                <xsl:value-of select="../DG1_4_DiagnosisDescription/text()" />
              </DG1_4_DiagnosisDescription>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="../DG1_5_DiagnosisDateTime/TS_0_Time">
              <DG1_5_DiagnosticDateTime>
                <xsl:value-of select="../DG1_5_DiagnosisDateTime/TS_0_Time/text()" />
              </DG1_5_DiagnosticDateTime>
            </xsl:if>
            <DG1_6_DiagnosticType>
              <xsl:value-of select="../DG1_6_DiagnosisType/text()" />
            </DG1_6_DiagnosticType>
          </DG1_Diagnosis>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </form1>
  </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[
public string ConvertSex(string sex)
{
if (sex == "F")
return "Female";
else
return "Male";
}


public string TSTime ()
{
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string ts = now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    return ts;
}



public string MyConcat()
{
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string ts = now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
    return ts;
}



]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that is the exact XML (except for the snipping) that you are processing? This error message suggests you are missing a root element enclosing all the other elements, but your example has one and should be OK.

Comment: Yes Ben it is exact. Actually, when I create an instance of the schema in visual studio, it has this - <ns0:ADT_A01_25_GLO_DEF xmlns:ns0="http://microsoft.com/HealthCare/HL7/2X">. Since I was getting the error message, I thought is was safe to replace it by "<root>" and try. What do you think ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the error message "XML document must contain a root level element." refers to the *output* XML, because it is empty!

So, why is it empty? The reason is that your XSL stylesheet templates are selecting non-existent nodes. For example, you have:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root" />
</xsl:template>
```

However, your example code root node is `<root/>`, so this select will not match it.

Additionally, the namespaces in your input XML and XSL stylesheet do not match. In both the XSL and XML, you need xmlns:s0 to have the same value.

For example, your XSL will produce some output if applied to the following input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?>
<s0:Root xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema">
  <PID_PatientIdentification>

  Content

  </PID_PatientIdentification>
</s0:Root>
```

Comment: Clever and cool. I will give it a try, Ben. I had no clue where to look, but now it has changed. Thanks a lot :-))

Comment: Would you mind to tell me how you would write the first lines in the inpur file ? I get errors in VS. Sorry about this. I'll be ok I think, once I see the code. Thanks

Comment: I'll be away for two weeks, so people answering, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have edited my answer to give an example of input XML that works with your XSL. However, I don't know anything about BizTalk and whether this XML is reasonable.